# parameter passing mechanism in R

Tags: r

The following function is used to multiply a sequence `1:x` by `y`

```
f1<-function(x,y){return (lapply(1:x, function(a,b) b*a, b=y))}
```

Looks like `a` is used to represent the element in the sequence `1:x`, but I do not know how to understand this parameter passing mechanism. In other OO languages, like Java or C++, there have `call by reference` or `call by value`.

Comment: To multiply a sequence x by a constant y just do (1:x) * y...like (1:3)*2 outputs 2, 4, 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To multiply a vector x by a constant y just do

```
x * y
```

The *(some prefix)apply* functions works very similar to each other, you want to map a function to every element of your vector, list, matrix and so on:

```
x = 1:10
x.squared = sapply(x, function(elem)elem * elem)
print(x.squared)
[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

It gets better with matrices and data frames because you can now apply a function over all rows or columns, and collect the output. Like this:

```
m = matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
# The 1 below means apply over rows, 2 would mean apply over cols
row.sums = apply(m, 1, function(some.row) sum(some.row))
print(row.sums)
[1] 12 15 18
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: `R` is `call by value`. Long answer: it can do both.

## Call By Value, Lazy Evaluation, and Scoping

You'll want to read through: [the R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) for more details.

`R` mostly uses `call by value` but this is complicated by its lazy evaluation:

So you can have a function:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
   x * 3
}
```

If you pass in two big matrixes to `x` and `y`, only `x` will be copied into the callee environment of `f`, because `y` is never used.

But you can also access variables in parent environments of `f`:

```
y <- 5
f <- function(x) {
   x * y
}
f(3) # 15
```

Or even:

```
y <- 5
f <- function() {
  x <- 3
  g <- function() {
    x * y
  }
}
f() # returns function g()
f()() # returns 15
```

## Call By Reference

There are two ways for doing `call by reference` in R that I know of.

One is by using [Reference Classes](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/ReferenceClasses), one of the three object oriented paradigms of R (see also: [Advanced R programming: Object Oriented Field Guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html))

The other is to use the `bigmemory` and `bigmatrix` packages (see [The bigmemory project](http://www.bigmemory.org/)). This allows you to create matrices in memory (underlying data is stored in C), returning a pointer to the `R` session. This allows you to do fun things like accessing the same matrix from multiple R sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple way to multiply a sequence by a constant, definitely use @Fernando's answer or something similar. I'm assuming you're just trying to determine how parameters are being passed in this code.

`lapply` calls its second argument (in your case `function(a, b) b*a`) with each of the values of its first argument `1, 2, ..., x`. Those values will be passed as the first parameter to the second argument (so, in your case, they will be argument `a`).

Any additional parameters to `lapply` after the first two, in your case `b=y`, are passed to the function by name. So if you called your inner function `fxn`, then your invocation of `lapply` is making calls like `fxn(1, b=4), fxn(2, b=4), ...`. The parameters are passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the help of `lapply` to understand how it works. Read this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega/7141669#7141669) to get and a good explanation of different xxpply family functions.

From the help of `laapply`:

```
lapply(X, FUN, ...)
```

Here FUN is applied to each elementof X and  ... refer to:

> ... optional arguments to FUN.

Since FUN has an optional argument b, We replace the `...` by , b=y.

You can see it as a syntax sugar and to emphasize the fact that argument b is optional comparing to argument a. If the 2 arguments are symmetric maybe it is better to use `mapply`.